# Java help check loginIn class using .CSV files

Tags: java, string, csv, authentication

What I'm currently trying to do is retrieve information from a `.CSV` file which contains information about user loin credentials in the form:

```
UserName,Password,PropertyName,PropertyValue 
UserName,Password,PropertyName,PropertyValue
```

So I have found a way of separating username information using the split() function. I am now having severe difficulty in using this information in my CLI class where I search to see if the username entered into the command line of my program matches the username in my csv file and if it also match the password given. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class readCSV {
    private String[] userData;
    public void checkLogin() throws IOException
    {
        String fileName = "C:/Users/Sean/Documents/Programming assigment/Users.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try
        {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                {
                    String data = inputStream.next();
                    userData = data.split(",");
                }
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException er){
            System.out.print(er); 
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public String getLogin()
    {
        return userData[0];
    }
}
```

### CLI

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CLI
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private readCSV l1 = new readCSV();

    public void login() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Username:");
        String username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Password:");
        String password = input.nextLine();
        try{
            l1.checkLogin();
        }
        catch(Exception er){ System.out.print(er); }
```

Stuck on this line of code to check the username and password

Comment: userData[1] will have the password. You are not reading it at all.

Comment: *"I am now having severe difficulty in using this information in my CLI class where I search to see if the username entered into the command line of my program matches the username in my csv file and if it also match the password given."* ..OK.  What is your question?  BTW - I hope this is purely some exercise for learning Java, since we should not be putting password information into a `String`, let alone a CSV formatted file.

Comment: Yes its just a learning exercise for a login system using information from a .csv file the trouble I'm having is reading the information from the csv file ie the username and password and using in the CLI class where I check does it match the username and password entered

Comment: *"the trouble I'm having"* ..is forming a question?  Troubles, travails, and specifications are not a question.  Please, choose one question and ask it, or this is at risk of being closed as 'not a real question'.  Also, add @Jayan (or whoever) to notify them of comments.  I actually think their first comment (+1) was a big hint as to where to start looking to solve one of the ..potential questions that you might ask..

Answer (score 2):

Your program design is not very well thought out. Ideally, your `checkLogin` method should accept two `String` arguments for username and password, then return a `boolean` to determine if the login credentials are correct:

```
public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
    // Read CSV file, compare entries against provided username and password.
    // Return true if a match is found. Otherwise, return false.
}
```

And then obviously in your `login` method you would pass the inputted username and password into the `checkLogin` method:

```
boolean loggedIn = false;
try {
    loggedIn = checkLogin(username, password);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```